# Is There a Command Line to Setup a Video Aspect Ratio?

Tags: video, command-line, aspect-ratio

I want to change the video aspect ratio from 16:9 to 4:3.

Have you got a command line to write down?

Comment: It would help to know which video player you are using.

Answer (score 6):

For mplayer:

```
mplayer -aspect 16:9
```

For VLC:

```
vlc --aspect-ratio 16:9
```

For Xine (seem to be limited to predefined values):

```
xine --aspect-ratio <mode>   Set aspect ratio of video output. Modes are:
                             'auto', 'square', '4:3', 'anamorphic', 'dvb'.
```